# Explanation about a proof regarding the standard topology

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation, solution-verification

I don't understand the argument at [26:00-27:14](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1wyOoLUjUeI&lc=z220xnlbjkmvhvzjp04t1aokgfw2by4wjc42shonqnlcrk0h00410.1580514347220018). Where did he use the definition of the standard $\mathbb{R}^d$ topology? It seems that the empty set is in any family of sets by that proof which is clearly nonsense.

---

A youtube snapshot is helpful - compare the definition of $\mathcal U$ on the left side of the board to the right side where he proves  $\emptyset \in \mathcal U$.

[image]

Comment: I couldn't follow all of it because I find the definition of "the standard R[sup]d[/sup] topology".  But it appears that what he proves (at time 26 minutes into the lecture) is that the empty set is a **subset** of any set, not that it is a member of a specific collection of sets.

Comment: I would realy like to see some explanation before the down vote. What is wrong with the question?

Comment: @user247327 This is not what he proves here. I'm not sure why you think that. He proves that the empty set is an element of the topology.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I would expect someone of your reputation to do your best to make questions self-contained. If that video goes down, this question becomes far less useful to others.

Comment: The proof shows that the empty set belongs to every family $\mathscr{F}$ of sets *that is defined by a condition* $S \in \mathscr{F} \iff \bigl(\forall p \in S : \text{whatever}\bigr)$.

Comment: I'm talking about the indicated part of the video that you linked. $\mathcal{O}_{\text{st}}$ is defined by $U \in \mathcal{O}_{\text{st}} \iff \bigl(\forall p \in U : \exists r \in \mathbb{R}^+ : B_r(p) \subseteq U\bigr)$. The proof shows — though that's not quite explicitly stated — that the empty set belongs to every family of sets defined by such a condition. (Because the part after "$U \in \mathcal{O}_{\text{st}} \iff \bigl(\forall p \in U :$" isn't used at all; $\forall p \in \varnothing : \ldots$ is vacuously true.)

Comment: So if I define some family $F$ of sets  with property $P$ then $\emptyset$ is in this family because $∀p∈\emptyset$:… is vacuously true @DanielFischer

Comment: If $P(S)$ is of the form $\forall p \in S : \ldots$, then yes. If the property has a different form, then $\varnothing$ may or may not have that property.

Comment: Yes, this make sense now. He actually proved that emptyset is open for much larger class of families no just family made in standard $R^d$ topology. He could mentioned that and there would be no confusion (for me of course). Also proofs with contradiction (which are equivalent to EFQ) are much easier to understand.  Thanks@DanielFischer Can you please write this comments as an answer.

Comment: This reminds me of the fact that the number of bijective mappings between the empty set and itself is equal to $1$. Can anyone say $0! = 1$.

Comment: See also [Base and empty set of a topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/490276/432081).

Answer (score 3):

On the left hand side of the board, the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^d$ is defined by: A subset $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ is in the standard topology, if and only if $\forall p \in U: \exists r > 0$ s.t. $B_r(p) \subseteq U$.

With this definition, the empty set is indeed in the standard topology. We just need to check that $\forall p \in \emptyset: \exists r > 0$ s.t. $B_r(p) \subseteq \emptyset$. However, this is trivially true, since there are no $p \in \emptyset$.

More precisely, the statement is true since we have

$$\forall p,\exists r > 0: p \in \emptyset \Rightarrow B_r(p) \subseteq \emptyset$$

However, this means that for every $p$ we have $\text{false} \Rightarrow \text{something}$, which by Ex falso quodlibet, is a true sentence.

---

Also, the proof does not show that the empty set is in any family of sets. This is not true. For example, consider the following collection of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ defined via $S:= \{U \subseteq \mathbb{N} \vert 1 \in U\}$. It does not contain the empty set.

However, the proof does show that for any collection $A$ of sets defined by $U \in A$ if and only if $\forall p \in U: \text{something}$ the empty set is a member.